# How to call functions in the original page(tab) in Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm now making a Chrome Extension. I want to call JS functions that are defined in the original page (tab), from Chrome Extension. It doesn't matter whether `background.html` or `Content_Script` calls them.

For example:

Original page (tab)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Original Page</title>
<script>
function greeting(){
    alert("Ohayou!");
    // some other codes here
}
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Then I want to call the function "greeting" in the original page, from Google Extensions.
How can I do the above?

Comment: You have to inject code into the original page. Rob W has explained it very well over here: [**Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879)

Comment: Thank you.
So one thing I can do is to inject a code that is called from Chrome Extensions and that calls a function in original page.

I mean
 Chrome Extension --> injected code in the original page --> original function in the original page

My understanding is correct??

Comment: Because the answer is a bit longer than this fields allows, I wrote a reply to your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the first part you can use this nice answer: [Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879).

To call a function back in your content script is easy. You can [create your own event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent) which you can then listen on in your content script.
This would work like this:

**injected code**:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
evt.initEvent('myCustomEvent', true, false);

// fire the event
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

**contentscript**:

```
document.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', function() {
  // do whatever is necessary
});
```

Comment: I want to call a function, that define on the page script file. Please Help

Answer (score 34):

Edit: **This solution is obsolete** since Manifest V3 (i.e. January 2022 in Chromium-based browsers) which prevents executing arbitrary (e.g. insecure) JavaScript in a page.

You can also simply write in your content script:

```
location.href="javascript:greeting(); void 0";
```

Comment: Refused to execute JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: I get that this works. I don't get why this works. location.href is the link of the origin, setting it equal to that string or `javascript:Whatever-Function-You-Want-To-Call-On-Your-Page();` opens that function call in a VM in debugger and executes the local code. I see that's what happens, but how? Why? Why does this work???

Comment: won't work with Manifest 3