# How to save value for later use in my content script using this function

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, location-href

I was looking for a way that my custom extenison runs a site defined function and returns its value for my later use in the extensions content script.

This is a very handy solution that I found and it executes the site defined function:

```
location.href="javascript:siteFunction(); void 0";
```

source: [How to call functions in the original page(tab) in Chrome Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290456/how-to-call-functions-in-the-original-pagetab-in-chrome-extensions)

But this only executes sites function and thats it, the function that I need returns the value I need later in my code. How can I get that value to be remembered for that later use?

Edit: For example, that site function returns a boolean value, and in my code I have an if that checks which of those is it, and then it runs the code needed.

Comment: Send a CustomEvent to your listener in the content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Could you write a simple example for this?

Comment: There are lots of easily googlable examples, here's one: [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)